# B-Tree implementation in secondary-memory/disk-memory

Tags: c, tree, file

I will start by saying this implementation was based on the approach taken with B-Trees in the book:

*Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition - Cormen, 2011*

The implementation stores all the b-tree nodes in a binary file, and constantly writes and reads from the said file in order to add new ones and to update the nodes information.

The file created is organized and treated like an array, the tree keeps track of the numbers of nodes it has and where each one is, so, when a new key/item is added a new position in the file/array is given/added.

To access directly to the node in the file fseek() is used to "jump" directly to the node location, witch gives the file "the array like properties".

Note: the print method prints the tree starting from the root and to do so it requieres a queue, that i will also provide for testing purposes.

This implementation lacks the delete method and other small but usefull methods, like get min/max item, etc... because before i tackle those i want to know if the current ones are good.

Methods Implementaded:

- Crete B-Tree
- Insertion
- Search
- Print tree

The code is highly commented, so will abstain from explainning how the algorithm of the functions works, but if requested, i will update the post.

From the tests i ran the implementation worked as expected, but i must say i didnt do an extensive testing.

I am sorry if the question got "too big", the essential code to be reviewed is the **btree.c** one

**btree.c**

```
#include "btree.h"

//#############################################################################
//                               HELPER METHODS
//#############################################################################

btNode disk_read(int disk, int order, FILE *fp){
    btNode read_node;

    // calculate the nº of bytes a node has
    int size_of_btNode = (sizeof(int) * 3) + (sizeof(element) * order-1) + (sizeof(int) * order);

    int offset = size_of_btNode * disk;    // calculate the position of the node in the file
    fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);           // set the file pointer there


    fread(&read_node.numKeys, sizeof(read_node.numKeys), 1, fp);    // read the information from the file
    fread(&read_node.isLeaf, sizeof(read_node.isLeaf), 1, fp);
    fread(&read_node.pos_in_disk, sizeof(read_node.pos_in_disk), 1, fp);

    read_node.keys = malloc(sizeof(element) * order-1);
    fread(read_node.keys, sizeof(element), order-1, fp);

    read_node.kids = malloc(sizeof(int) * order);
    fread(read_node.kids, sizeof(int), order, fp);


    return read_node;
}

void disk_write(btNode node, int order, FILE *fp){

    // calculate the nº of bytes a node has
    int size_of_btNode = (sizeof(int) * 3) + (sizeof(element) * order-1) + (sizeof(int) * order);

    int offset = size_of_btNode * node.pos_in_disk;              // calculate the position of the node in the file
    fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);                                 // set the file pointer there

    fwrite(&node.numKeys, sizeof(node.numKeys), 1, fp);          // write the information to the file
    fwrite(&node.isLeaf, sizeof(node.isLeaf), 1, fp);
    fwrite(&node.pos_in_disk, sizeof(node.pos_in_disk), 1, fp);
    fwrite(node.keys, sizeof(element), order-1, fp);
    fwrite(node.kids, sizeof(int), order, fp);
}

btNode new_node(int order, int is_leaf) {
    btNode n;

    n.numKeys = 0;                                 // set nº of keys to 0
    n.isLeaf = is_leaf;

    n.keys = malloc((order-1) * sizeof(element));  // allocate space for the array of keys
    for(int i=0; i < order-1; i++){                // initialize the keys in the array
        n.keys[i].key = -1;
        n.keys[i].data = -1;
    }

    n.kids = malloc((order) * sizeof(int));        // allocate space for the array of keys
    for(int i=0; i < order; i++){                  // initialize the kids in the array
        n.kids[i] = -1;
    }

    return n;
}

void bt_split_child(btNode x, int pos, bTree *tree, FILE *fp, int split_root){

    btNode y = disk_read(x.kids[pos], tree->order, fp); // node to split (pos-th child)
    if(split_root == 1){                                // special case when splitting the root of the tree
        tree->node_count++;                             // increment nº of total nodes
        y.pos_in_disk = tree->node_count;               // attribute a new location in the file
    }
    btNode z = new_node(tree->order, y.isLeaf);         // new (pos+1)-th child
    tree->node_count++;                                 // increment nº of total nodes
    z.pos_in_disk = tree->node_count;                   // attribute a new location in the file
    int t = (tree->order / 2);                          // calculate minimum ramification degree

    if(tree->order % 2 == 0){
        t--;
    }
    z.numKeys = t;                                      // nº of keys the new node will receive

    if(tree->order % 2 != 0){
        t--;
    }
    for(int j = 0; j <= t && (j+t+1)<= y.numKeys-1; j++){ // move elements to new node
        z.keys[j] = y.keys[j+t+1];
        y.keys[j+t+1].key = -1;                         // erase the element from the previous node
        y.keys[j+t+1].data = -1;
    }

    if(y.isLeaf == 0){                                  // if y is not a leaf
        for(int j = 0; j <= t; j++){                    // move children as well
            z.kids[j] = y.kids[j+t+1];
            y.kids[j+t+1] = -1;                         // erase the element from the previous node
        }
    }
    y.numKeys = t;                                      // update the nº of keys the node has after split


    if(split_root == 1){                                // special case when splitting the root of the tree
        x.kids[pos] = y.pos_in_disk;
        x.kids[pos+1] = z.pos_in_disk;
    }else{
        int j, i, r;
        for(j = 0; j < tree->order;j++){                 // make room for x`s new child
            if(x.kids[j] == y.pos_in_disk){
                for(i = j+1; i < tree->order;i+=2){
                    if(i+1 < tree->order)
                        x.kids[i+1] = x.kids[i];
                }
                r = j;
            }
        }
        x.kids[r+1] = z.pos_in_disk;
    }


    for(int j = pos; j < tree->order-2; j+=2){           // make room for the element
        x.keys[j+1] = x.keys[j];                         // that will be promoted
    }

    x.keys[pos] = y.keys[t];                             // promote element
    y.keys[t].key = -1;                                  // erase the updated element from the previous node
    y.keys[t].data = -1;
    x.numKeys++;                                         // increment the nº of keys the root node has

    disk_write(x, tree->order, fp);                      // update the information in the file
    disk_write(y, tree->order, fp);                      // update the information in the file
    disk_write(z, tree->order, fp);                      // update the information in the file
}

btNode bt_insert_nonfull(btNode node, element key, bTree *tree, FILE *fp){

    int pos = node.numKeys;

    if(node.isLeaf == 1){                                      // if in a leaf insert the new element
        int i = pos-1;
        while(i >= 0 && key.key < node.keys[i].key){           // find the correct position
            node.keys[i+1] = node.keys[i];
            node.keys[i].key = -1;
            node.keys[i].data = -1;
            i--;
        }
        if(i+1 != pos){
            node.keys[i+1] = key;
        }else{
            node.keys[pos] = key;
        }
        node.numKeys++;
        disk_write(node, tree->order, fp);
        return node;
    }else{                                                     // otherwise, descend to the appropriate child
        int n_pd = node.pos_in_disk;
        int i = pos-1;
        while (key.key < node.keys[i].key && i >= 0) {         // get the correct child of the node
            i--;
            pos--;
        }

        btNode x = disk_read(node.kids[pos], tree->order, fp); // get the child node
        if(x.numKeys == tree->order-1){                        // is this child full?
            bt_split_child(node, pos, tree, fp, 0);            // split the child
            btNode x1 = disk_read(n_pd, tree->order, fp);      // get the updated node
            if(key.key > x1.keys[pos].key)                     // adjust the position if needed
                pos++;
        }
        btNode x1 = disk_read(n_pd, tree->order, fp);          // get the updated node
        btNode x2 = disk_read(x1.kids[pos], tree->order, fp);  // get the child node
        bt_insert_nonfull(x2, key, tree, fp);
    }
}

//#############################################################################
//                               METHODS
//#############################################################################


bTree *btCreate(int order){

    bTree *tree;                                // creates the "header" of the B-Tree
    if((tree = malloc(sizeof(bTree))) == NULL)  // allocate space for the new tree
        return NULL;

    btNode root = new_node(order, true);        // creates the root of the new B-Tree
    root.pos_in_disk = 0;                       // give the root a position in the file

    tree->order = order;                        // give the tree it`s order
    tree->root = root;                          // give the tree it`s root
    tree->node_count = 0;                       // set the tree`s node count to 0

    return tree;

}

void btInsert(bTree *tree, element key, FILE *fp){
    if(tree->node_count > 0)
        tree->root = disk_read(0, tree->order, fp);           // update the root of the tree
    btNode root = tree->root;

    if(root.numKeys == tree->order-1){                        // if the root is full
        btNode s = new_node(tree->order, 0);                  // create a new root node
        s.kids[0] = root.pos_in_disk;                         // root becomes the first child
        bt_split_child(s, 0, tree, fp, 1);                    // split the root
        s = disk_read(0, tree->order, fp);                    // get the new root
        tree->root = s;                                       // make it the new root after the split
        bt_insert_nonfull(s, key, tree, fp);                  // now insert the new element
    }else{
        tree->root = bt_insert_nonfull(root, key, tree, fp);  // insert the new element in a non-full node
    }

}

int btSearch(btNode node, int order, element key, FILE *fp){

    int pos = 0;
    while(pos < node.numKeys && key.key > node.keys[pos].key){  // find the correct position
        pos++;
    }
    if(pos <= node.numKeys && key.key == node.keys[pos].key){   // is the item one of the key`s of this node?
        return node.pos_in_disk;
    }else if(node.isLeaf == 1){                                 // if a leaf was hit and no item was found
        return -1;
    }else{
        btNode x = disk_read(node.kids[pos], order, fp);        // go deeper in the tree
        return btSearch(x, order, key, fp);
    }
}


void print_node_keys(btNode node, int order){
    printf("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < order-1; i++){
        if(node.keys[i].key != -1)
            printf("key: %d, ", node.keys[i].key);
    }
    printf("] ");
}

void btPrintTree(bTree *tree, queue *q,FILE *fp){
    btNode end = { .numKeys = -1};                    // marker to know when a level of the tree ends
    insert(q, tree->root);                            // insert the root in the queue
    int item_count= 1;                                // real item/node counter
    while(!isEmpty(q)){
        btNode current = removeData(q);               // remove the first item in the queue and return that node
        if(current.numKeys == -1){                    // was a marker found?
            printf("\n");
            insert(q, end);
            if(item_count == 0)                       // to avoid and endless loop of markers
                break;                                // when the tree is already printed
        }else{
            item_count--;
            print_node_keys(current, tree->order);
            if(current.pos_in_disk == 0)              // special case for the root
                insert(q, end);
            for(int i = 0; i < tree->order; i++){     // insert all the kids os the next node in the queue
                if(current.kids[i] != -1){
                    btNode x = disk_read(current.kids[i], tree->order, fp); // get the kid
                    insert(q, x);
                    item_count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**btree.h**

```
#ifndef BTREE_H
# define BTREE_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "queue.h"


//#############################################################################
//                               STRUCTS
//#############################################################################

typedef struct element{
    int key;              // the key of the element
    int data;             // that data that each element contains
}element;

typedef struct btNode{
    int numKeys;          // nº of keys the node has
    int isLeaf;           // is this a leaf node? 1 = true, 0 = false
    int pos_in_disk;      // position of the node in the file
    element *keys;        // holds the keys of the node
    int *kids;            // holds the children of the node
}btNode;

typedef struct bTree {
    int order;            // order of the B-Tree
    btNode root;          // root of the B-Tree
    int node_count;       // total nº of nodes the tree has
} bTree;

typedef struct queue queue;

//#############################################################################
//                               METHODS
//#############################################################################

// create a new empty tree
bTree *btCreate(int order);

// return nonzero if key is present in tree
int btSearch(btNode node, int order, element key, FILE *fp);

// insert a new element into a tree
void btInsert(bTree *tree, element key, FILE *fp);

// print all keys of the tree from the root
void btPrintTree(bTree *tree, queue *q,FILE *fp);

// read and returns a node from the file
btNode disk_read(int disk, int order, FILE *fp);

#endif
```

**queue.c**

```
#include "queue.h"


queue *createQueue(int size) {
    queue *q;
    if((q = malloc(sizeof(queue))) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if((q->list = malloc(sizeof(btNode) * size)) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    q->size = size;
    q->front = 0;
    q->rear = -1;
    q->itemCount = 0;
    return q;
}

btNode peek(queue *q) {
    return q->list[q->front];
}

bool isEmpty(queue *q) {
    return q->itemCount == 0;
}

bool isFull(queue *q) {
    return q->itemCount == q->size;
}

int size(queue *q) {
    return q->itemCount;
}

void insert(queue *q ,btNode data) {

    if(!isFull(q)) {

        if(q->rear == q->size-1) {
            q->rear = -1;
        }

        q->list[++q->rear] = data;
        q->itemCount++;
    }
}

btNode removeData(queue *q) {
    btNode data = q->list[q->front++];

    if(q->front == q->size) {
        q->front = 0;
    }

    q->itemCount--;
    return data;
}
```

**queue.h**

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
# define QUEUE_H


#include "btree.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


//#############################################################################
//                               STRUCTS USED
//#############################################################################

typedef struct element element;
typedef struct btNode btNode;
typedef struct bTree bTree;

typedef struct queue{
    int size;
    int front;
    int rear;
    int itemCount;
    btNode *list;
}queue;

//#############################################################################
//                               METHODS
//#############################################################################

queue *createQueue(int size);
btNode peek(queue *q);
bool isEmpty(queue *q);
bool isFull(queue *q);
int size(queue *q);
void insert(queue *q ,btNode data);
btNode removeData(queue *q);

#endif
```

Small testing program:

**test.c**

```
#include "btree.h"
#include "queue.h"

int main(){

    element n1 = {.key = 20};
    element n2 = {.key = 30};
    element n3 = {.key = 10};
    element n4 = {.key = 40};
    element n5 = {.key = 15};
    element n6 = {.key = 17};
    element n7 = {.key = 18};
    element n8 = {.key = 50};
    element n9 = {.key = 60};
    element n10 = {.key = 70};

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("file.bin", "wb+");

    bTree *tree = btCreate(4);

    btInsert(tree, n2, fp);
    btInsert(tree, n1, fp);
    btInsert(tree, n3, fp);
    btInsert(tree, n4, fp);
    btInsert(tree, n5, fp);
    btInsert(tree, n6, fp);
    btInsert(tree, n7, fp);
    btInsert(tree, n8, fp);
    btInsert(tree, n9, fp);
    btInsert(tree, n10, fp);


    queue *q = createQueue(15);

    btPrintTree(tree, q, fp);

    int pos = btSearch(tree->root, tree->order, n10, fp);
    if(pos != -1) {
        btNode x = disk_read(pos, tree->order, fp);
        printf("node has: %d keys", x.numKeys);
    }else
        printf("item doesnt exist!");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reading and Writing from the disk**

You have the same code in `disk_read` and `disk_write` to calculate `size_of_btNode`.  This can be moved into a helper function to avoid the code duplication.  In this calculation you use `sizeof(int) * 3`, while for the actual read or write you're using `sizeof(read_node.numKeys)` etc.  You should use the sizeof the 3 variables you're reading rather than assuming they are always an `int`.

Similarly, the calculation of `offset` is repeated.

These two functions are very similar.  It is possible to merge them into one function which would avoid the duplication of the I/O code.

There is no error checking or handling in the disk operations.

**Node creation**

`new_node` leaves the `pos_in_disk` field uninitialized.  It also makes assumptions about the types it is allocating memory for.  Using `sizeof(*n.keys)` rather than `sizeof(element)` would get rid of that.  (Same for `kids`.)

**Node insertion**

In `bt_insert_nonfull` the condition

```
    if(i+1 != pos){
        node.keys[i+1] = key;
    }else{
        node.keys[pos] = key;
    }
```

can be reduced to one line, since the code in both branches does the same thing (since in the `else` branch, `pos` will equal `i+1`).

**`numKeys` meaning**

The way it is used in the code, sometimes it seems that `numKeys` is the number of keys, other times that it is the index of the last valid key (which is one less than the number of keys).  Comparisons with `tree->order-1` or `pos<=node.numKeys` point to the latter, while other code for creating new nodes or inserting looks like the former.  These need to be checked and a consistent usage applied throughout.

**Miscellaneous**

`btCreate` and `createQueue` have the same issue with `sizeof` using a specific type as other uses of `sizeof`.

There are numerous `btNode` structures passed by value to functions.  In some cases these can be replaced with passing by `const btNode *` to avoid the copy.

Comment: Thanks, i will take your notes and improve the code